# Cannot Reload Tableview from custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `tableview` cells. One of my `Cell` has a `UITextField`, I'm handling the `textfield` delegate methods in the custom `tableviewCell` class. I need to reload the `tableview` once the user entered a text, I had done the below thing but not worked , Any idea please help me.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
    [parentTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: are you getting any exception ??

Comment: No exceptions, not reloading..

Comment: I dont think you can get the superview that is the tableview inside the cell!! And so this code is not working. Try using a delegate or an observer. That would solve the issue i guess

Comment: why u create another tableview Object for it..? if you use IBOutlat of TableView ten simply reload like `[tableOutlateName reloadData];` and else u can Reload with `[self.tableview reloadData];`

Comment: Are you sure you've set the delegate of the text field correctly?  Put an `NSLog` or a breakpoint in your `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method to verify it.

Answer (score 3):

Register the view controller to receive notifications that the data has been changed, and have it refresh the table when it receives one. Then have the parser send it out.

Registering for it is easy:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTableView:)
                                             name:@"reloadTableView"
                                           object:nil];
```

Your refresh method needs to be set up to receive these notifications, along these lines:

```
- (void)reloadTableView:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self.yourTableName reloadData];
}
```

And it's important to stop observing in your ViewDidUnload:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Then in the parser you need to simply add this when it's complete:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTableView" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

The view controller (and anyone else observing the notification with that name) will get the message and perform its task.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

## CustomCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^tapHandler)(NSUInteger tag);
```

## CustomCell.m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSUInteger tag = 10; //Need to change the tag
    self.tapHandler(10);
}
```

## Controller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
 {
    // Whatever content was previously there. Add the below line in addition

     cell.tapHandler = ^(NSUInteger tag){
        [tableView reloadData];
    };

    return cell
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

first , the superview of the textfiled is not UITableview, it is tableviewcell or tableviewcell.contentview (depends on your code)

then, you just need to set the tableview as your view controller's member ,or property,

then

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.parentTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep a reference of table view in `CustomCell`

```
 // interface
 UITableView *tableView;

 // propery 
 @property (nonatomic)UITableView * tableView;
```

Then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //your stuff
  cell.tableView= tableView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)textField.superview.superview;
[parentTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By `(UITableView *)self.superview;` you will not get the table view. Try below code :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[[textField superview] superview]; // you will get cell
      UITableView *table = cell.superview; // you will get table view
      [table reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload whole table view for that small operation. Just reload the Cell in which the text field is. Also didnot forget to update your data source as table view cell fetch the data from the data source while the cell is loading.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [tableViewDataSource addObject:textField.text];//this will fill the data source with data of textfield
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)textField.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [parentTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    [parentTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableReload++;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d%d",indexPath.row,tableReload];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";


    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is plain out wrong and has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self.yourTableName reloadData];
   [self.yourTableName reloadInputViews];
}
```